# TreeView Not Displaying Images from ImageList

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a `TreeView` that displays `CheckBox`es:

[image]

I want to check if a given directory contains an ".mdf" database and if it does, check whether it is attached on the selected server instance. If the database is attached I display an image against that node, and a different image if it is not attached. Note: The images are .png format, size 32x32...

I populate an `ImageList` from `Properties.Resources`

```
mainImageList = new ImageList();
mainImageList.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.Database);
mainImageList.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.DatabaseGrey);
```

I then loop through the tree and add the relevant image

```
public static void RecursiveAddImage(TreeNode treeNode, List<string> attachedList)
{
    if (String.Compare(Path.GetExtension(treeNode.Text), ".mdf", true) == 0)
    {
        string databaseName = treeNode.Text.Replace(".mdf", String.Empty);
        if (attachedList.Contains(databaseName))
        {
            treeNode.ImageIndex = 0;
            treeNode.SelectedImageIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            treeNode.ImageIndex = 1;
            treeNode.SelectedImageIndex = 1;
        }
    }
    foreach (TreeNode node in treeNode.Nodes)
        RecursiveAddImage(node, attachedList);
}
```

The above code goes through the loop with no complaints, finds ".mdf"s and seems to add the relevant `ImageIndexes` but these do not show up in the `TreeView`. What am I doing wrong here and can I add the `ImageList` at design time (something I also can't seem to do)?

I have read several posts and ofcourse the [MSDN documantation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.imageindex.aspx) but I still can't seem to get it working. Any help as always, is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the TreeView's ImageList property set to `mainImageList`?

Comment: That was it. So so stupid. Appologies. I will accept this as the answer if you can be bothered to copy and paste! :'[

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the TreeView control has the `ImageList` property set to the correct `ImageList` reference:

```
mainImageList = new ImageList();
mainImageList.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.Database);
mainImageList.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.DatabaseGrey);

treeView1.ImageList = mainImageList;
```

Comment: Do you know how I can add an ImageList in the Desiger within VS2010 to save me having to initilise?

Comment: @Killercam For images in `Properties.Resources`?  No.  Clicking Add on the dialog box only brings up an file dialog box.  For just adding an ImageList component to your form, it's in "All Windows Forms" and in the "Components" tool boxes.  Just double-click it and it will appear in the component bar underneath the form designer.

Answer (score 2):

`TreeNode.StateImageIndex= 0;` would set the imagelist images. Make sure the imagelist is binded to Treeview control as mentioned above.